# How to repeat earlier parts of code • Luau

Tags: python, lua

Now, I'm not amazing with words, so bear with me.

So I am creating a program within Lua, but I've run into a problem. I am making a bank sorta program, and I what it does is it asks for a PIN number, and then you are able to withdrawal or deposit. But, I want it to go back to asking for the PIN number after you deposit or withdrawal.

I am able to do that in Python:

```
while True:
    pin = input("PIN: ")
    if pin == 21171:
        -- code
    elif pin == 21172:
        -- code
```

So that asks for pin, runs code in one of the if statements, then when all code is run in if statement it goes back to asking for PIN. This is what I wanna do in Lua, but how?

Comment: Google is a useful tool: [while loops](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.2.html), [if statements](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html), [IO library](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend *Programming in Lua*. https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html

```
while true do
  io.write("PIN: ")
  local pin = tonumber(io.read("*line"))
  if pin == 21171 then
      -- code
  elseif pin == 21172 then
      -- code
  end -- if
end -- while
```